# How can I check if a JAR file is valid?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, classpath

My webapp allows a user to upload a JAR file. However, after the jar file is uploaded, it is corrupted. I have verified this by comparing the MD5 checksums before and after uploading the file (winmd5free).

The uploaded jar file is almost identical to the original:

- The file size compared to the original is similar (at the KB level)
- I can open the uploaded jar file using an unzipping program and view it's contents (resources and class files), and everything is the same compared to the original file

When I open up the uploaded jar file (using Notepad++), I did notice that the binary contents are different from the original. Also, when I used `JarInputStream` to read the JAR entries, there were no entries.

```java
JarInputStream is = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("uploaded.jar")));
JarEntry entry = null;
while(null != (entry = is.getNextJarEntry())) {
    System.out.println(entry.getName());
}
```

Furthermore, when I double click on the jar (Windows), I get the following message.

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile

My questions are:

- Is there a way to programmatically check if a jar file is valid? I would have expected `JarInputStream` to detect this right away, but it shows no problems at all
- When I double click on the jar file, in windows, is it java.exe that is giving me the "invalid or corrupt JAR file" message?
- How come when an invalid jar file is passed in as part of the classpath, no error/exception is thrown? For example, by running the `java -cp uploaded.jar;libs\* com.some.class.Test` command?

This question is irrelevant from jar signing and/or checking the signature of a JAR file. It is simply checking if a file (uploaded or not) is a valid JAR file (not necessarily if the jar's class files are valid, as there is another SO post on this issue already).

My results for running `jar -tvf uploaded.jar`:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:88)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:977)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:222)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
```

Comment: On the command line, run the jar command like this: `jar -tvf <jarname>`.  The 't' says "test", 'v' I believe means "verbose", and 'f' means "file".  You can also open a JAR in any ZIP program.

Comment: thanks, i will use java.util.zip.ZipFile to see if i can programmatically check (see modified addition of stack trace from running those options with the jar tool).

Comment: @CodeChimp `t`is for "List Contents of JAR file" as you can see in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html so it don't test checksums of contents (although it need to be a more o less valid jar to list the entries).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A way to programmatically detect an invalid jar file is to use `java.util.ZipFile`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length < 1) {
        System.err.println("need jar file");
        return;
    }
    
    String pathname = args[0];
    try {
        ZipFile file = new ZipFile(new File(pathname));
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = file.entries();
        while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = e.nextElement();
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If the jar file is invalid, a `ZipException` will be thrown when instantiating the `ZipFile` object.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html is another option.