# Getting "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar" while bootstrapping the Corda netwrok

Tags: blockchain, corda

While trying to bootstrap the Corda network getting below error.

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar

Please find more details below.

```
root@domestic-lc:/home/POC_DomesticLC# java -jar corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.0.jar --dir build/nodes
Bootstrapping local test network in /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes
Using corda.jar in root directory
Generating node directory for PartyB
Generating node directory for BankB
Generating node directory for Notary
Generating node directory for BankA
Generating node directory for PartyA
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [PartyA, PartyB, BankB, BankA, Notary]
Found the following CorDapps: []
Not copying CorDapp JARs as --copy-cordapps is set to FirstRunOnly, and it looks like this network has already been bootstrapped.
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
#### Error while generating node info file /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes/PartyA/logs ####
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar
#### Error while generating node info file /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes/PartyB/logs ####
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar
#### Error while generating node info file /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes/BankA/logs ####
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar
#### Error while generating node info file /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes/BankB/logs ####
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar
#### Error while generating node info file /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes/Notary/logs ####
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile corda.jar
Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /home/POC_DomesticLC/build/nodes/PartyA/logs.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (not with that particular JAR file, but I'm using that file's name in my examples).  Here's how I worked out what was wrong.

These troubleshooting steps may help others who find this issue (but not the OP as the dates show it can't be this issue).

I started by trying to validate the JAR file by [inspecting its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152195/how-to-check-if-a-jar-file-is-valid):

```
$ jar -tf corda.jar
```

This showed me that it was indeed invalid.  In my case, I saw:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:126)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1115)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:293)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

I then looked at the size of the file:

```
$ ls -alh corda.jar
```

In my case, it was 133 bytes, which seems a bit small for a JAR file, so I `cat`ed it and saw this:

```
$ cat corda.jar

501 HTTPS Required. 
Use https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
More information at https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required
```

It turned out that my script (a Dockerfile in fact) was downloading the file with `curl -o` but from a URL which was no longer supported.  As https://links.sonatype.com/central/501-https-required says:

> Effective January 15, 2020, The Central Repository no longer supports insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS.
>
> If you're receiving this error, then you need to replace all URL references to Maven Central with their canonical HTTPS counterparts:
>
> Replace http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ with https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
>
> Replace http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ with https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
>
> If for any reason your environment cannot support HTTPS, you have the option of using our dedicated insecure endpoint at http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/
>
> For further context around the move to HTTPS, please see https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https.

This is fairly specific, but may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get over this issue?

I've tried with bootstrap 4.0 but I didn't see any issue, so my suggestions are:

- check your java version, make sure it is 1.8.171+
- make sure the corda.jar (in your build /nodes/notary/corda.jar) is correct because bad network may cause the incomplete corda.jar downloaded
- make sure you've got the tools from official website instead of copying from other way where the bootstrap jar file might be broken
- last, as always, please try to use the latest version bootstrap: 4.3, to utilise the best Corda:
  https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-tools-network-bootstrapper/4.3/